# Can't change the mapleader of vim

Tags: vim

I am trying to configure vim on my Mac. I put the .vimrc file on my home directory and try

```
let g:mapleader=','
```

and

```
let mapleader=','
```

but neither of them works. The mapleader is still the backslash.

I searched around the Internet and found no answer. It appears not to be a problem for most of people. So I am wondering what did I do wrong.

Comment: Are other configurations working? add some other configurations and check if its able to get config from .vimrc

Comment: You need spaces on each side of the equal sign: `let mapleader = ","`.

Comment: Your leader has to be set before any mappings you make. That may be your problem -- do you create mappings before setting your leader?

Comment: @romainl ?! It is a matter of coding style, not a requirement of any kind. I used to assignment without spaces for years.

Comment: @pandubear Thank you for your answer! That worked. I placed the code at the end before but when I moved it to the front it started to work fine. I am just wondering why? Why does the order matter?

Comment: @ZyX, it's important for `:set` and doesn't matter for `:let`. It's good to follow conventions, though.

Comment: From `:h mapleader`: 'Note that the value of "mapleader" is used at the moment the mapping is defined.  Changing "mapleader" after that has no effect for already defined mappings.' I suppose when you create a mapping with `<leader>` in it, Vim just substitutes your leader into it right there, or something like that.

Comment: @romainl I did not say a word about `:set` here. There are no conventions for `:let` I know about, neither there is some official style guide (in fact I do not know even non-official one, but I believe there should be some).

Comment: @pandubear That's right! I put a bunch of code before. I just learned to use Vim and I was just appending everything I know to the end of .vimrc . Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Be sure to put your mapleader as early as possible in your .vimrc file. The value of the leader is used during mapping definitions, it's not updated everytime you set mapleader.
2. Use double quotes ("), not single quotes (')